# writing command line output to file

Tags: python, macos, file, unix, ls

I am writing a script to clean up my desktop, moving files based on file type. The first step, it would seem, is to `ls -1 /Users/user/Desktop` (I'm on Mac OSX). So, using Python, how would I run a command, then write the output to a file in a specific directory? Since this will be undocumented, and I'll be the only user, I don't mind (prefer?) if it uses `os.system()`.

Comment: What files do you want to move? Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html for file operations using Python.

Comment: Shell script is enough for this

Comment: If you use shell scripts, read more about pipes and redirection.

Comment: I am not talking about creating a seperate .sh file. A combination of `for`, `if`, `file` would be enough.

Comment: If you're not creating a shell script you shouldn't be using `ls`. In fact, even if you are creating a shell script your should be using `find` for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can redirect standard output to any file using `>` in command.

```
$ ls /Users/user/Desktop > out.txt
```

Using python,

```
os.system('ls /Users/user/Desktop > out.txt')
```

However, if you are using python then instead of using `ls` command you can use `os.listdir` to list all the files in the directory.

```
path = '/Users/user/Desktop'
files = os.listdir(path)
print files
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named system.

Comment: @Suda.nese how are trying to import? What is your Python version?

Answer (score 3):

After skimming the python documentation to run shell command and obtain the output you can use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module with the `check_output` method.

After that you can simple write that output to a file with the standard Python IO functions: [File IO in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1):

To open a file, you can use the `f = open(/Path/To/File)` command. The syntax is `f = open('/Path/To/File', 'type')` where 'type' is r for reading, w for writing, and a for appending. The commands to do this are `f.read()` and `f.write('content_to_write')`. To get the output from a command line command, you have to use popen and subprocess instead of `os.system()`. os.system() doesn't return a value. You can read more on popen [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).