# Redirection opeartors, < and >, in os.system(cmd)

Tags: python, shell, jython, io-redirection

It is recommended that os.system is used for executing commands from python scripts. Furthermore, it is claimed that redirection operator work in there. For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003615/1083704) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197565/1083704). I do

```
os.system("ls > out.txt")
```

This works indeed on one of my computers. Another produces

```
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access out.txt: No such file or directory
```

I am a bit limited on the other with access right to investigate which process produces this message. But `os.system("ls")` lists the files like charm. Both are Windows 7 machines.

Comment: *It is recommended that os.system*. No, actually, it is not. You should use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: `>` redirection is dependent on the shell being executed; `os.system()` passes the string to a shell process and if that process doesn't support `>` then you get an error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why `os.system` is not recommended?

Comment: @thefourtheye This means that Martijn Pieters does not recommend this.

Comment: I wonder how which are those different shells on Windows 7 installations and which of them fails to support the > redirection.

Comment: @thefourtheye: `os.system()` is low-level, and a security hole waiting to happen (as soon as you mix in untrusted data into the shell call shell exploits are just an escape character away). `subprocess` gives you much more flexibility and lets you avoid using a shell altogether.

Comment: @Val Even then, it is Martijn Pieters who doesnt like it. So, there will be a good reason behind it :)

Comment: Quoting from the documentation of [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.system): "The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; **using that module is preferable to using this function.** See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the `subprocess` documentation for some helpful recipes."

Comment: @Val I was more curious which version of Windows 7 had `ls` as a command :)

Comment: @JonClements every version, once cygwin installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Err no... as Martijn commented - it's not recommended - use `subprocess`, e.g.:

```
import subprocess

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    subprocess.check_call('ls', stdout=fout)
```